# Make Laravel 5.1 work on a specific production environment

Tags: php, laravel, production

I want to deploy a Laravel 5.1 application on a production server, but with a little specific configuration. I want this app to be accessible at the http://hexaconf.fr/version-dynamique/, because for the moment, the root of the site must show the "The site is coming, see you soon" page.

What configuration is necessary to see the Laravel app when I type "hexaconf.fr/version-dynamique" in my browser?

Comment: Have you looked here? http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration

Comment: @KA_lin there's nothing there on this subject.

Comment: @Remi Bertin Looks like you're running Apache, so you can have a look at [this article](http://mackhankins.com/blog/laravel-5-virtual-host-for-an-apache-subdirectory).